# Can I create my own variable which should work like built in variable in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to create my own variable and want to set my default value which should work like a built in variable in Informatica. I want to use created variable in my all workflow.

Is it possible any way ?

Thanks

Comment: This [thread](https://network.informatica.com/thread/46167) might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same parameter file across all of your mappings (there is syntax to separate out bits which are for specific sections and those which are universal by way of the scope) see following link https://network.informatica.com/thread/27560

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Is there any way by Admin Console or .profile file ?

Comment: Hi Bipin, it depends where you want to use the variable... .profile file is environment variables for some flavours of unix thus if you set a variable in the informatica user's .profile file, those variables will be available for all of your command tasks. Where do you anticipate using the aforementioned variables? In workflow connection conditions across workflows? In session logic for a mapping? Somewhere else?

Comment: This kb may well be what you're after https://kb.informatica.com/howto/3/Pages/113646.aspx

Comment: Hi Daniel, Link given by you (kb.informatica.com/howto/3/Pages/113646.aspx) is really useful for me and that is what I wanted. Thank You